# How do I change FcgidMaxRequestLen on my web server?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

Ok I did lots of research but still things are confusing.

Basically I have a php file that is an form and I keep getting Internal Server Error when the file is larger than roughly 5mb. I have increased all the settings in php.ini file like max upload and increased timeout. I checked the error log on my web server and it says:

"mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 16777688 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (16777216)"

I made an SSH connection and edited the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf and added the line FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824 and attempted to increase it to 1GB.

My server has 2GB so I think I am good. I restarted apache and then tried to upload a file again and got the same error "mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 16777688 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (16777216)" the max size did not change. I am on a godaddy vps server. Maybe there is a place in plesk. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: moving from the worst web host on the planet would be my first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't provide a ready-to-go help but at least some points to investigate as I stumbled over this topic today, too:

- the request length is not the default you see in the logs (see http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-mod_fcgid-http-request-length-exceeds-maxrequestlen)

=> Therefore I presume that 16777216 is somewhere defined on a "lower" level via plesk.

Your configuration changes the system wide default (from 131072) which is nevertheless overwritten by plesk.

Might be an overdose, but did you try to grep through apache's config folder?

Answer (score 4):

I recognize the question being quite old, but nevertheless maybe my answer is helpful to someone:

You can overwrite the value of `FcgidMaxRequestLen` per domain in your Plesk configuration under 
`Plesk -> Domains -> domain.tld -> Apache & Nginx settings -> Additional directives for HTTP & HTTPS` e.g.

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 100
FcgidProcessLifeTime 7200
</IfModule>
```

See here: https://talk.plesk.com/threads/problems-overwriting-fcgidmaxrequestlen.337579/#post-799693

Comment: Note: you need to be signed in to see the paragraph "Additional Apache directives"